# Can I use "whose" as the relative word of "country" in an arrtributive clause?

Tags: word-usage

For example, in the sentence below:

> All the countries _____ life expectancy dropped had taken an average of 5 years to achieve just a one-year increase in life expectancy.

Can I use "whose" here? If not, what should I use? (My teacher says I should use "where" here, but I don't understand why.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: countries are places, so "where" makes perfect sense. "who" works as well, as MichaelHarvey says in his answer. Either one can work.

Comment: I'm CV'ing because the answer is easily found in various sources; e.g., [M-W online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whose) provides two examples in which the antecedent is not a person.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use 'whose' to introduce an attributive relative clause such as 'whose life expectancy dropped'. The antecedent (e.g. 'countries') does not have to be a person.

> The map shows all the countries whose athletes have been
> suspended for doping.
>
> A general table for all the countries whose special trade can be
> quoted would be quite chaotic.
>
> When such a person is elsewhere than in any of the countries of which
> he is a national, he may be claimed as a national by all the countries
> whose nationality he possesses.

Comment: I've never been certain how this came about, but some people seem to like 'where' to *avoid* 'whose' for non-people… perhaps because they really, really want to use 'whiches' - but there's no such word ;) You could use 'in which' but that's a bit too formal.